# String (not just letter) to ConsoleKey c#

Tags: c#, console-application

So i need to convert string to ConsoleKey...

Yes something like this works:

```
string ch = "a";
ConsoleKey ck = (ConsoleKey)Convert.ToChar(ch);
```

But what if the string is like "UpArrow" (the string is from ReadKey input and saved to txt file)

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a string to an enum member using [`Enum.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [`Enum.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Unfortunately the API is not generic, so you have to specify the type a few times:

```
ConsoleKey key1 = (ConsoleKey)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleKey), "UpArrow");
```

The above will throw an exception if the string is not a member of the enum. To protect against that you could use:

```
if (Enum.TryParse("UpArrow", out ConsoleKey key2))
{
    // use 'key2' in here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!